# How to disable Virtualbox auto-close

Tags: virtualbox

When my computer reaches 4% battery, Virtualbox shuts off. How can I disable this or change when it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual contains:

**Battery Low** The battery level reached a critical level (usually less than 5 percent charged).

> This event is currently only handled on Windows hosts and Mac OS X hosts. When this event is generated, VirtualBox will save the state and terminate all VMs in preperation of a potential host power down.
>
> The behavior can be configured. By executing the following command, no VM is saved:
>
> ```
>  VBoxManage setextradata global "VBoxInternal2/SavestateOnBatteryLow" 0
> ```
>
> This is a global setting as well as a per-VM setting. The per-VM value has higher precedence than the global value. The following command will save the state of all VMs but will not save the state of VM “foo”:
>
> ```
>  VBoxManage setextradata global "VBoxInternal2/SavestateOnBatteryLow" 1
>  VBoxManage setextradata "foo" "VBoxInternal2/SavestateOnBatteryLow" 0
> ```
>
> The first line is actually not required as by default the savestate action is performed.